# Return documents with desired values in MongoDB, filter, c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Example of a structure in the database:

```
{
    id: 0,
    Numbers: [5, 10, 11]
}
{
    id: 1,
    Numbers: [11, 512, 7, 28]
}
```

If I make a filter like this:

```
List<int> n = new List<int>() { 7, 11 };
var filter = builder.Eq("Numbers", n);
```

Mongodb does not return a single item - as it seems to understand the equivalence `{7, 11}` clearly
the question is: how do I design a filter so that mongodb only returns the 2nd element - in other words: I need a clear filter condition - for example `{7, 11}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to use the [All](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_Query_All.htm) method

```
List<int> n = new List<int>() { 7, 11 };
var filter = builder.All("Numbers", n);
```